# limit of ln(x) is negative infinity?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits-without-lhopital

I have a question on this specific question from my textbook.

[image]

How is limit of $\ln(x^2)$ as $x$ approaches $0$ equal to $-\infty$?

Shouldn't it be undefined?

Since this chapter is without l'Hospital's rule, I would like to know without using the rule.

Comment: Why do you think it is undefined?

Comment: @angryavian Since ln(0) is undefined due to there being a vertical asymptote.

Comment: The limit of a function at some point (e.g., $0$) is well-defined regardless of the value of the function at the point (even if the function is not defined there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\ln (x^2)$ is defined for any $x\in\mathbb R \setminus\{0\}$ and therefore the limit exists, indeed just take $y=x^2 \to 0^+$ then

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \ln (x^2)=\lim_{y\to 0^+} \ln y=-\infty$$

Comment: How does ln(y) equal to -inf if y is positive inf?

Comment: Recall the [graph](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log+x) for $\ln x$.

Comment: oh thank you that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

$|x|<e^{-\frac M 2}$ implies $x^{2} <e^{-M}$ which implies $\ln (x^{2}) <-M$. By definition of limit this gives $\lim_{ x \to 0} \ln (x^{2})=-\infty$.

Comment: sorry but i'm not familiar with M in your answer... What does M mean? I'm a complete beginner and would like to know in simpler terms please.

Comment: Here is the definition: $lim_{x \to a} f(x)=-\infty$ if given any real number $C$ there exists $\delta >0$ such that $|x-a| <\delta$ implies $f(x) <C$. Take $a=0$ in this  I am just writing $M$ for $-C$ to indicate that we are really interested in negative numbers with large absolute value. @ericsmcs